# In eventsourcing how does my publisher application know a command was successful with many subscribers

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, rabbitmq, event-sourcing

I've planned to build multiple applications to learn more about how I can use event sourcing in .net.

This is my planned architecture so far.

[image: Architecture]

So f.ex both web app 1 and web app 2 can create users so when web app 1 creates a user he sends a command msg with the user properties to rabbitmq and the event handlers 1 & 2 use the needed properties to create a user in respective db.

What I don't understand is

f.ex

A visitor on Web App 1 creates an account.

Web App 1 sends the UserCreatedAccount message to rabbitmq

Both event handlers subscribe to message and create a user in respective db

Now, **how should web application 1 know that a user really has been created ? should it just assume that everything went fine and let the user through ?**

Is my architecture plan missing something ?

I won't be generating an aggregate from the event store, but just store the current state of an object in respective db.

Comment: In the *particular* example you give, `rabbitmq` could return an HTTP response code indicating success or failure. Or you could have WebApp1 wait 15 seconds and then just blindly try to log the user in. If the creation failed, that'll fail. Another common pattern I see with tedious regularity would have `rabbitmq` send the user a confirmation email when the account is created. A link in the email sends the user back to WebApp1 to log in. For a slow `rabbitmq`, that would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I won't be generating an aggregate from the event store, but just store the current state of an object in respective db

Firstly, it doesn't sound like you're actually implementing event-sourcing. In event sourcing it's the event store that's the source of truth for the state of your aggregates.

Secondly, your diagram shows that the web apps send commands to rabbitmq. Are you planning to put both events and commands there? It's not very clear if you're trying to implement event-sourcing or command-sourcing or both or neither.

This indecision becomes most apparent here:

> Web App 1 sends the UserCreatedAccount message to rabbitmq
>
> ...
>
> Now, how should web application 1 know that a user really has been created ?

The thing about events is that they are facts. If the UserCreatedAccount event happened then its undeniable - it's a fact. If your webapp is not sure if it's true or not, if the user has been created or not, then it must not emit such an event.

I think what you are really trying to do (which is more consistent with the diagram) is that the webapp issues a CreateUserAccount *command*. That command is picked-up by a *command-handler* that, if successful, actually emits the UserCreatedAccount event. Since commands can fail (events cannot - they're always in the past), now the web app has a legitimate reason to wonder if it succeeded or not.

Now onto the solutions.

The web app can monitor the events emitted by the command-handlers to know if the command failed or not (a correlation id will come in handy) but it would also have to be able to time-out (or possibly retry). This will get complicated and will depend on the desired latency and how errors are meant to be communicated.

An alternative is to use rabbitmq only for the events but send commands directly from the web app to the command handler. This way you can still implement event sourcing properly but have a "normal" call from the web app to the command handler, so that you get the response back whether it succeeded or failed. To add location-transparency to this, I'd consider using something like akka.net for this bit.

Answer (score 0):

> In eventsourcing how does my publisher application know a command was successful with many subscribers

The usual answer in event sourcing is that the publisher knows a command was successful when the book of record acknowledges that it has been updated successfully.

Subscribers don't necessarily see those updates immediately (key search term: eventual consistency).

Thus, the usual design is that events get written to a durable event store first, and only after that do they get put onto a queue that will distribute them to the subscribers.

Thus, the durable event store acts the book of record -- the single source of truth in your system, and the subscribers have reflections of that truth.

(The underlying issue being that messages can get lost, or re-ordered, and you need a way to recover from those conditions).

If the messages are commands, then we typically have an aggregate that translates the command into new events to write to the store.  If the messages are events (FormSubmitted is an event, as is HttpRequestReceived), then you don't need an "aggregate", as such, just synchronous write to ensure that the change has been made durable.